# Graphics with frame labels written in terms of a parameter

Tags: graphics, ticks

Assume that variable `pointList` contains the coordinates of some random points, each of which is expressed in terms of `L`, for example:

```
pointList = {{0.5 L, 0.5 L}, {0.8 L, 1.3 L}, {1.5 L, 1.0 L}};
```

I want to view these points in a framed graphics whose axes are expressed in terms of `L`, namely this:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: ``ListPlot[pointList /. L -> 1, Ticks -> {Table[{L, L "L"}, {L, Subdivide[0, 2., 10]}]}, PlotRange -> Full, AspectRatio -> 1]``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Domen for your comment on my question.
I wrote the following code and got what i wanted:

```
fticksLeftBot[min_, max_] := Table[
   If[Mod[i, 4] == 0.0, {i 0.05, i 0.05 "L", {0.016, 0.0}}, {i 0.05, , {0.009, 0.0}}],
   {i, Floor[min/0.05], Ceiling[max/0.05]}];
fticksRightTop[min_, max_] := Table[
   If[Mod[i, 4] == 0.0, {i 0.05, , {0.016, 0.0}}, {i 0.05, , {0.009, 0.0}}],
   {i, Floor[min/0.05], Ceiling[max/0.05]}];
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[ReplaceAll[pointList, L -> 1.0]]}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{fticksLeftBot, fticksRightTop}, {fticksLeftBot, fticksRightTop}}]
```

The result is:

[image]